# (Unity 3D) How to make a player's object move in it's own axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was wondering how to make a player move in it's own axis. When the player's object rotates I want it to move forward, not in global direction. The player rotates when the camera rotates. Here's both scripts.

Player Movement

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float playerSpeed;

    private float moveX;
    private float moveY;

    void Update()
    {
        moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed;
        moveY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed;

        transform.position += new Vector3(moveX, 0, moveY);
    }
}
```

Camera Controller

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Numerics;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraControler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject CameraFocusObject;
    public GameObject CameraPart;

    public Transform orientation;

    float xRot, yRot;

    public int sensX;
    public int sensY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * sensX;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * sensY;

        yRot += mouseX;
        xRot -= mouseY;
        xRot = Mathf.Clamp(xRot, -85f, 85f);

        transform.rotation = UnityEngine.Quaternion.Euler(xRot, yRot, 0);
        CameraFocusObject.transform.rotation = UnityEngine.Quaternion.Euler(0, yRot, 0);
    }
}
```

I'm new in programming in Unity, so if you can be more specific in the answer that would be helpful.

Comment: You can get the current forward vector by using [`Transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html). See the example in the doc for details on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is to move your character in the Camera.forward direction.

1. you could use the camera.main.forward direction vector to rotate your character in the direction of the Camera, this could be used if you want a little delay in the walking direction change, for example:

   `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(camera.main.transform.forward);`

Then all you need to do is, to let your character walk in its own forward direction (`transform.forward += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed`)

2. you could use your Camera.forward for the direction your player should walk in directly

   `transform.position += camera.main.transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed`

I Hope that helps :)

P.s. i would recommend using privat fields instead of public, this is more clearly if you are working in multiple scripts in one namespace (you can use "[SerializeField] private GameObject XXX") <= this will expose your fields in the inspector even when they are private.

Also you should get rid of the "using Unity.Editor" usings, they will break your Build, when you want to make a final version of your game :)

Cheers'